# Getting getters from Java 17 subclasses, DTO

Tags: java, json, dto

What could be the problem ?

I have a DTO class where I get john , after which I need to pull these values out of there and set them to another object.

Previously, I did it via VS code and everything worked fine. I moved these classes to the INTELLIJ IDEA after which I can't get the values from this class.

Example DTO UPDATE:

```
    public class GetModel {
        
            @JsonProperty("vendor")
            private String vendor;
           
            private List<Result> result = null;
          
           //get/set
            
    @JsonProperty("result")
    public List<Result> getResult() { 


 return result; 
}
@JsonProperty("result") 
public void setResult(List<Result> result) { 
this.result = result; 
}
        
           
           class Result {
        
                @JsonProperty("FIELDS")
                private Fields fields;
               
        
                //get/set
               
                 class Fields {
        
                      @JsonProperty("adress")
                      private String adress;
                   
                //get/set
                  }
        
            }
        }
```

I am creating an object to set a value from a class GetModel

Example:

```
GetModel info;

Show show = new Show();

show.setAuthorityCyr(info.getResult().get(0).getFields().getAdress());
```

but I cannot get to it, respectively, and get the value.
the same project with the same code (only Java 11 was used) it gave these parameters.

Here Java 17 is used and does not give meaning.
Only in the context menu it shows incomprehensible fields as indicated in the image:
[image]

how to get to the values to set them in this case?

UPDATE

POJO :

```
 public class Show {
   
// other fields 
  
    @JsonProperty("cyr")
    private String authorityCyr;
    

   @JsonProperty("cyr")
    public String getAuthorityCyr() {
        return authorityCyr;
    }

    @JsonProperty("cyr")
    public void setAuthorityCyr(String authorityCyr) {

        if(authorityCyr !=null){
            this.authorityCyr = authorityCyr;
        } else if(authorityCyr==null){
            this.authorityCyr = "null";
        }
    }
// other get/set

}
```

Comment: Show your `setAuthorityCyr` in POJO.

Comment: and is your `.getResult()` a list, that is why you are doing .get(0)?

Comment: What is the return type of `getResult()`?

Comment: updated the POJO. 
The fact is that the code was the same on IDE, and everything worked fine there witch .getResult().get(0) .
What needs to be done for this now?

Comment: @Hulk @JsonProperty("result")
public List<Result> getResult() {
return result;
}

@JsonProperty("result")
public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
    
this.result = result;
}